# Sum of DateTime difference in sql (HH.MM)

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have SQL Table like Where DateDiff is in format (hh.mm)

```
DateDiff   ATM
1.45       121
1.50       121
1.50       121
```

When i do `Sum` of DateDiff by `Group by` on ATM it will show result like

```
4.45    121
```

But the actual Date Time Difference should be

```
5.25     121
```

How can we achieve the same in SQL Query

```
Select Sum(Cast(Convert(Varchar(10),DATEDIFF(HOUR,TicketRaisedOn,ClosedOn))+'.'+
Convert(Varchar(10),DATEDIFF(MINUTE,TicketRaisedOn,ClosedOn)%60) as Numeric(18,2)))[Down Time],ATM 
From Ticket Where Closed=1 And DATEPART(DAYOFYEAR,GETDATE())=DATEPART(DAYOFYEAR,TicketRaisedOn) 
Group BY ATM Order By [Down Time] Desc
```

`TicketRaisedOn` & `ClosedOn` are of DateTime

Database is SQL Server 2008

Above query will print result like this (But its wrong as it will sum it as number not as date time format)

```
Down Time       ATM
16.95           282
14.46           1811
14.20           52
14.04           936
```

Sample Data

```
Select TicketRaisedOn,ClosedOn,ATM 
From Ticket 
Where ATM=282 And DATEPART(DAYOFYEAR,GETDATE())=DATEPART(DAYOFYEAR,TicketRaisedOn) 
And Closed=1

TicketRaisedOn          ClosedOn                ATM
2012-12-21 01:15:23.793 2012-12-21 15:11:59.240 282
2012-12-21 16:42:29.820 2012-12-21 18:21:30.797 282
```

Comment: I suspect that as Numeric(18,2) it comes after the conversions and before the sum

Comment: Is the data above the result from the query?  If so, then can you post data from your table?

Comment: Some data and table structure for fields `TicketRaisedOn,ClosedOn, Closed`?

Comment: @bonCodigo TicketRaisedOn & ClosedOn are DateTime datatype in sql. I am just retrieving Current Date Records. and Closed is Bit

Comment: The first line may be misleading, the data in the table is stored as `DATETIME` and the required output is HH.MM

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do the summing before the formatting

```
SELECT
  ATM,
  CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), SUM(DATEDIFF(Minute, TicketRaisedOn, ClosedOn)) / 60)
  + '.' +
  RIGHT('00' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(2), SUM(DATEDIFF(Minute, TicketRaisedOn, ClosedOn)) % 60), 2)
FROM Ticket
GROUP BY ATM
```

Sql Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/eca01/1

Comment: This could end up as 11:6 instead of 11:06 - you need to left-pad the right-side.

Answer (score 3):

What you are doing doesn't work, because 1.5 represents one and a half hours, *not* one hour and 50 minutes.

To get what you want, do the arithmetic in a small unit, such as seconds, then convert this to a datetime, and then the datetime to a final representation.  Here is an example:

```
select right(convert(varchar(255),
                     DATEADD(second, DATEDIFF(s, TicketRaisedOn,ClosedOn), cast(0 as datetime)),
                     120),
             8)
```